# How to write/read hex values from serial port in Lua?

Tags: lua, serial-port, hex

I have to program a device which uses hex commands to be run.
While I am used to it using Python or Matlab, in my case I have to use a Lua script embedded inside a proprietary software...

I tried first to make it work using Matlab :

```
clear all
close all
s = serial('COM9','BaudRate',115200, 'DataBits',8);

fopen(s);
% %%Specify hex codes to be transmitted
txdata = ['FF';'22';'08';'00';'19';'64';'14';'28';'3C';'50';'64';'78';'8C';'AA';'19';'19';'19';'19';'32';'32';'32';'32';'01';'02';'01';'01';'01';'01';'01';'01';'61';'1E';'00';'01';'36'];
%Convert to decimal format
txdata_dec = hex2dec(txdata);
%Write using the UINT8 data format
fwrite(s,txdata_dec,'uint8');
%Read back data in decimal format
rxdata_dec = fread(s);
% Convert data back to hexadecimal format
rxdata = dec2hex(rxdata_dec)
fclose(s)
delete(s)
clear s
```

How to do the equivalent in Lua without additional libraries please?

Thank you very much !
Ben

I tried something like this but it does not work...

```
os.execute[[mode COM9: baud=115200 parity=N data=8 stop=1]]

s = io.open("COM9","w") 
io.output(s) 
io.write(0xFF, 0x22, 0x08, 0x00, 0x19, 0x64, 0x14, 0x28, 0x3C, 0x50, 0x64, 0x78, 0x8C, 0xAA, 0x19, 0x19, 0x19, 0x19, 0x32, 0x32, 0x32, 0x32, 0x01, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x61, 0x1E, 0x00, 0x01, 0x36)

io.read("all") 
io.close(s)
```

Comment: `io.write(0xff)` will write `"255"` to the stream. You most likely want to use `string.char(0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f)` which translates these values to chars: `"Hello"`. Can't say anything about COM interface, not on a Windows machine.

Comment: `w` mode in `io.open` means you only write, no read at all.